# Na pendura? Cliffhanger

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Um termo que acho um pouco difícil de traduzir é [cliffhanger](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliffhanger), no contexto de "Recurso de roteiro em filmes/TV/livros".

Qual é a tradução apropriada para o português do termo?

Em um exemplo:

> The final episode finished in a *cliffhanger*, leaving the poor audience waiting till the next summer for the next episode.

*Gancho* é um termo que ouvi, mas não tenho certeza que é a melhor opção. Na entrada da [Wikipédia *PT*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliffhanger_(recurso_de_roteiro)), eles usam o mesmo termo do inglês.

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo de frase? Pelo o que eu sei, é estar pendurado a beira de um abismo com risco eminente de morte. Também é uma técnica de produção onde deixa "um gancho" para a próxima cena ou capítulo. Acredito que seja essa tradução que está procurando?

Wikipedia-> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliffhanger_(recurso_de_roteiro)
Linguee->http://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/cliffhanger.html

Comment: Melhorei um pouco a pergunta. E sim, estou a procura de *um gancho* :P !

Answer (score 2):

**Cliffhanger**

Ou literalmente *pendurando no penhasco* é aquela situação em que o herói parece que será derrotado/vai morrer mas acaba se salvado (da maneira mais "heróica" possível). É um recurso de roteiro muito explorado em filmes de ação para gerar comoção no público.

Provavelmente o termo remete a alguma cena clássica de algum antigo filme do gênero em que o herói se agarra a um arbusto para não cair num precipício.

Dado o exemplo:

> The final episode finished in a cliffhanger...

Eu poderia tentar algo como:

> O episódio final terminou em uma cena de perigo/tensão (inconclusa)...

Mas no caso *se* eu fosse traduzir isso eu tentaria descreveria a cena

> E o último episódio terminou com nosso herói com a vida por um fio...